# Clonar o Sincronizar repositorio

Tags: git, github

Tengo un proyecto creado en localhost, lo que he hecho es subirlo por github, y cada vez que hago cambios genero un commit y push, y estos cambios van subiendo al repositorio.

En otro computador para no dejar mi cuenta abierta, lo que habia hecho hasta ahora es descargar el repositorio cada vez y sobreescribir la carpeta en el otro computador, y todo estaba marchando bien.

Hasta que agregaron unos archivos de configuracion en el otro computador, que de seguir haciendo lo que normalmente hacia, voy a borrar estos archivos al momento de bajar manualmente y sobreescribir.

Asi que ahora me veo obligado a configurar el git en el otro pc, y empezar a hacer Pull cuando tenga cambios, para solo modificar los archivos que tienen cambios.

¿Como puedo ahora hacer una "sincronizacion" de esos archivos, sin que vaya a borrar los archivos de configuracion que estan en ese proyecto actualmente?

si hago un clone de mi proyecto al otro pc, seguro que borro los archivos de configuracion que ya estan.

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que dices de los archivos de configuración. Si el repositorio está actualizado en GitHub, puedes hacer un `git clone` del mismo en el nuevo equipo local y seguir trabajando en ese nuevo equipo, haciendo luego `git add .`, `git commit` y `git push` cada vez que cambies algo, para reflejar esos cambios en tu respositorio remoto.

Comment: Si, pero hay digamos unos archivos nuevos, en el otro pc que yo no tengo, y que tampoco puedo subir a mi locahost. esos archivos pertenecen al otro pc, son parte de una configuracion interna de ese pc, si hago git clone, voy a borarr esos archivos y no puedo, quisiera tratar de hacer una integracion de solo mis archivos.

Comment: @wil Me ha sucedido lo mismo,  lo que yo hago es que cuando hago el "CLONE" hago una copia del contenido en un directorio aparte y en una carpeta indicada para tal proposito, luego  borro todos aquellos directorios y elementos que no requiero, posteriormente solo hago la copia del proyecto en su respectiva carpeta y listo.

Comment: También he recurrido cuando ya no se puede de otra manera, a descargar el proyecto desde el repositorio usando CLONE , se guarda, le borras las carpetas de configuración,   renombras el proyecto que quieres actualizar,  creas uno nuevo, pegas lo que depuraste del clone y configuras de nuevo el gitlab para que puedas hacer los commit  y push, al igual que las actualizaciones desde el mismo git configurado en tu IDE.

Comment: si son archivos de configuración de cierto pc y no se deben subir a **gitHub** puedes agregarlos a tu `.gitignore`

Comment: Si es un repositorio aparte lo propio sería hacer el `git clone` en una carpeta nueva, donde solo estarán los archivos de ese repositorio.

Answer (score 0):

En donde trabajo estamos utilizando el gitlab igual como muchos más como un repositorio de trabajo, tenemos varios proyectos ahí montados.

En nuestro caso hemos configurado el gitlab en cada equipo que esta relacionado con el equipo de desarrollo.  Para el desarrollo estamos utilizando PhpStorm, y en este caso en particular en la pantalla tenemos tres opciones para interactuar con el repositorio.

Desconozco si existe una manera de "sincronizar" automáticamente entre un equipo y el repositorio, por que esta parte nosotros lo hacemos de manera manual.

Al llegar a trabajar se nos indico que en cuanto se habrá el PhpStorm hagamos un "update"  El clic se debe hacer en una "flechita azul" que apunta hacia abajo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez hecho clic en esta flecha te aparece una ventanilla de notificacion que te pide confirmar la "actualización" del proyecto, "Merge incoming changes into the current branch"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aceptas te indicara cuantos y cuales son los archivos nuevos, o modificados, etc y los comenzara a descargar, si encuentra algún error, te notifica.

De esta manera es como se puede "sincronizar" el repositorio y el proyecto de manera local en tus equipos de trabajo de forma manual.

Es importante mencionar que cuando se haga un commit y un push

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verificar la lista de los elementos a cargar, evitar que cargue todo lo que esta relacionado a la carpeta .idea si utilizas PhpStorm y nbproject si utilizas NetBeans, y el que le corresponda según el IDE que utilicen ustedes.

Ya que como supongo ya les ha sucedido que se cargan algunos elementos de configuración contenidos ahí, estas carpetas y archivos ahí incluidos guardan informacion del proyecto y configuraciones locales, que ocasiona errores al cargarlos en otro equipo.

En la imagen que añado al final, se puede observar un elemento llamado unversioned Files, dentro de ese elemento tiene todos los archivos que se añadieron externamente como serian archivos de imagen, iconos, pdfs etc., etc.. Que no han sido añadidos o creados desde la interfaz del Phpstorm, incluso aquellos que realizando pruebas de carga de archivos se suben al repositorio de documentos del proyecto ahí te aparecen todos esos elementos. También trae los archivos de configuración local, de las carpetas IDEA y nbProject. En caso de que requieras algún archivo se puede indicar que los añada al commit desde ahí si los necesitas.

Confirmas Tu commit y el push y se actualizara en tu repositorio.

Cuando haces uso del CLONE hago que me descargue el proyecto y lo reviso antes de guardarlo en la carpeta destinada para el desarrollo, si trae la carpeta .idea, nbproject las elimino, y posteriormente solo corto y pego el proyecto de esta manera te evitas el sobrescribir las configuraciones.